# JSP: Where to place the error page?

Tags: java, jsp, web, error-handling

I have created an error page to handle any possible 404 and 500 http errors. 
I placed the error page in root and configured in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

It works very good.
But I am thinking where is the correct place to put my error.jsp? Is it a good way to put it in the root folder? Is it better to put it in WEB-INF? If so, how should I configure the path in web.xml?

Comment: As I know, WEB-INF is protected location. Class files, JAR archives used by the application are stored in there. So, it is not open to the clients of your application. My choice is also the root location for error files. However, you may create a particular folder (e.g. errors) under the root to store the distinct error pages.

Comment: WEB-INF/errors/yourerrpage.jsp

Comment: `WEB-INF/pages/error/error.jsp` generally